# Read second row in sqlite DB

Tags: ios, sqlite

I finally figured out how to connect to my DB. I sucessfuly read the first row of my query, but how do I get the second row?

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(localDB,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        NSString *st0 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
        NSString *st1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
        NSString *st2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
        NSString *st3 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3)];
        NSString *st4 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4)];
        NSString *st5 = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5)];

        NSLog(@"0: %@",st0);
        NSLog(@"1: %@",st1);
        NSLog(@"2: %@",st2);
        NSLog(@"3: %@",st3);
        NSLog(@"4: %@",st4);
        NSLog(@"5: %@",st5);
    }
    else
    {
       NSLog(@"%s","Match not found");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"%s","Error on SQLITE_OK");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use  `while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)` instead of `if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)`, then you will be able to iterate through every row.